# u-boot: memory allocation puzzle when booting kernel

Tags: u-boot

I am using petalinux 2023.2 to run a linux with soft microblaze on a FPGA board. I had a question regarding u-boot behavior in terms of possible memory allocation. The board/design has 2GiB DDR, ranges from `0x8000_0000` to `0xffff_ffff`, physically.

What the petalinux command does to boot into u-boot and then kernel via JTAG is the following (as shown with `petalinux-boot --verbose` option, line number is added by me):

```
 1 targets -set -nocase -filter {name =~ "microblaze*#0"}
 2 puts stderr "INFO: Downloading ELF file: /home/bruin/work/linux_mb/images/linux/u-boot.elf to the target."
 3 dow  "/home/bruin/work/linux_mb/images/linux/u-boot.elf"
 4 con
 5 
 6 after 1000; stop
 7 puts stderr "INFO: Loading image: /home/bruin/work/linux_mb/images/linux/linux.bin.ub at 0x80000000"
 8 dow -data  "/home/bruin/work/linux_mb/images/linux/linux.bin.ub" 0x80000000
 9 puts stderr "INFO: Loading image: /home/bruin/work/linux_mb/images/linux/system.dtb at 0x81e00000"
10 dow -data  "/home/bruin/work/linux_mb/images/linux/system.dtb" 0x81e00000
11 puts stderr "INFO: Loading image: /home/bruin/work/linux_mb/images/linux/rootfs.cpio.gz.u-boot at 0x82e00000"
12 dow -data  "/home/bruin/work/linux_mb/images/linux/rootfs.cpio.gz.u-boot" 0x82e00000
13 puts stderr "INFO: Loading image: /home/bruin/work/linux_mb/images/linux/boot.scr at 0xff200000"
14 dow -data  "/home/bruin/work/linux_mb/images/linux/boot.scr" 0xff200000
15 
16 con
17 exit
```

As shown above:

- line 3~4 loads `u-boot.elf` to ddr and then start executing it. Where `u-boot.elf` been located in ddr? As shown below, it starts from `0x8010_0000`.

```
xsct% dow u-boot.elf
Downloading Program -- /home/bruin/work/linux_mb/images/linux/u-boot.elf
        section, .text: 0x80100000 - 0x80148c7f
        section, .rodata: 0x80148c80 - 0x80156d1f
        section, .dtb.init.rodata: 0x80156d20 - 0x80159d3f
        section, .data: 0x80159d40 - 0x8015c35f
        section, .got: 0x8015c360 - 0x8015df13
        section, __u_boot_list: 0x8015df14 - 0x8015f00b
        section, .bss: 0x8015f3b4 - 0x801662c7
        section, .rela.dyn: 0x8015f00c - 0x8015f3b3
100%    0MB   0.2MB/s  00:01
Setting PC to Program Start Address 0x80100000
```

- as u-boot has a default 4 seconds delay before booting kenrel, line 6 pause the execution of u-boot during this 4-seconds delay.
- then line 8/10/12/14 download 4 data to ddr to their respective locations.
- line 16 continues u-boot execution, which reads `boot.scr` to execute the command `bootm 0x80000000 0x82e00000 0x81e00000` for booting into kernel.

My question is about line 7: the load address for `linux.bin.ub` (kernel image with u-boot header) is `0x8000_0000`, the size of `linux.bin.ub` is around 10MiB. But `u-boot.elf` text is within this memory region...how is it possible?

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or https://superuser.com/

Comment: SO is for questions about software development (and not just programming). Who but a SW developer would be concerned about how/where to load the kernel, rootfs, & DTB images for booting?  Vote to reopen; this question never should have been closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But u-boot.elf text is within this memory region...how is it possible?

During its initialization, U-Boot relocates itself to high  memory in order to maximize the amount of contiguous free memory.
See **arch/microblaze/cpu/relocate.c** and **start.S**